# Опечатка или фича в названии шапки Silencium

Tags: обсуждение, новогодние-шляпы

Шапка получаемая при условии:

> задайте вопрос, который не получит ни одного ответа в течении недели с момента публикации

называется Silencium, что не означает ничего. Однако, судя по всему, название шапки должно являться отсылкой к стихотворению Фёдора Ивановича Тютчева "Silentium!", что переводится как "[Тишина](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1281/p.1/index.html)". Является ли оригинальное название шапки опечаткой или так и должно быть?

Comment: Меня больше смущает _"в течении"_.

Comment: Скорее уж это отсылка к заклинаниям из Гарри Поттера

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это точно не опечатка. Иначе она остаётся незамеченной уже как минимум 2 года, согласно [результатам поиска по MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=Silencium).

Фёдор Иванович Тютчев, конечно, великий поэт, но я всё же сомневаюсь, что его стихотворение легло в качестве названия зимней шляпы.

Answer (score 2):

Почему вы думаете, что обычное латинское слово является отсылкой к стихотворению, названному этим словом, а не использовано просто само по себе? Это silence + ium для научности.

Comment: Я не знал, что шапке уже два года и мне показалось странным, что название ничего не означает, хотя кажется, что должно